# Merge multiple FileSystemInfo arrays into one FileSystemInfo collection

Tags: vb.net

I have created five `FileSystemInfo()` arrays from five different directories using the `DirectoryInfo.GetFileSystemInfos()` method.

I need to know how to combine all that five `FileSystemInfo` arrays into one single collection or, how I can get one `FileSystemInfo` collection from five different directories.

For example:

```
Dim dir1 As New DirectoryInfo(str_fromPath1)
Dim dir2 As New DirectoryInfo(str_fromPath2)
Dim dir3 As New DirectoryInfo(str_fromPath3)
Dim dir4 As New DirectoryInfo(str_fromPath4)
Dim dir5 As New DirectoryInfo(str_fromPath5)

Dim FSinfo1 As FileSystemInfo() = dir1.GetFileSystemInfos
Dim FSinfo2 As FileSystemInfo() = dir2.GetFileSystemInfos
Dim FSinfo3 As FileSystemInfo() = dir3.GetFileSystemInfos
Dim FSinfo4 As FileSystemInfo() = dir4.GetFileSystemInfos
Dim FSinfo5 As FileSystemInfo() = dir5.GetFileSystemInfos

Dim SINGLE_FSinfo_ALL As FileSystemInfo   ???
```

Comment: You can get a single list by creating a new list and using `AddRange` to add each array to the list

Comment: Thanks alot. Appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group all your arrays in a single *container* and use Linq's [`SelectMany()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany) to generate a `List(Of FileSystemInfo)` from the content of all the sub-arrays included.
Or create a new array in a similar way:

Generate a **`List(Of FileSystemInfo)`** from all the existing arrays:

```
Dim fsInfoList = {FSinfo1, FSinfo2, FSinfo3}.SelectMany(Function(arr) arr).ToList()
```

Or generate a new **`FileSystemInfo()`** array, which is the *sum* of all the others:

```
Dim fsInfo_All() = {FSinfo1, FSinfo2, FSinfo3}.SelectMany(Function(arr) arr).ToArray()
```

Or generate a **`FileSystemInfo()()`** jagged array instead.
In this case, all the elements in the single array collections are distinct from the others and still accessible using the *old* index:

```
Dim fsInfo_All = {FSinfo1, FSinfo2, FSinfo3}
```

► Another possibility. Why not organize your `FileInfo()` arrays in a single collection from the beginning, then extract the content of all (or a subset), if/when needed?
For example, using a **`Dictionary(Of String, FileSystemInfo())`**:

```
Dim allDirectories As New Dictionary(Of String, FileSystemInfo())()
allDirectories.Add("Some Path", New DirectoryInfo(SomePath).GetFileSystemInfos())
allDirectories.Add("Search Result", New DirectoryInfo(AnotherPath).GetFileSystemInfos())

' fsInfoAll is a List(Of FileSystemInfo)
Dim fsInfoAll = allDirectories.SelectMany(Function(dict) dict.Value).ToList()
```

In this case, you can also access the single collections by Key or Index.

Comment: Hi Jimi, it did not work and I am still stuck. I have 5 different directories , let us say c:\folder1  ,  c:\folder2 ,  c:\folder3 , D:\folder4 , E:\folder5        my question again. how I can make single (only ) one filesysteminfo      for all of the above directories to collect file infomation in only one filesysteminfo      thank you

Comment: You have to be more specific. What solution did you adopt? What does *did not work* mean? This is is something you need to explain, otherwise it's not possible to understand what the problem might be. What result did not meet the expectations? Here, you can see 4 slightly different methods to generate a single `FileInfo` collection from multiple Directories. These all *work*: a new collection (List, Array, Jagged Array or Dictionary) is generated from multiple sub-collections. The Dictionary solution is slightly different, since all collections are organized using the Root folder.

Comment: hi jimi i have updated my question below , Thanks for help

Comment: If your `function_CopyFiles` expects an array, then use the second method, e.g., `Dim FS_file_info_ALL = {FSinfo1, FSinfo2, FSinfo3, FSinfo4, FSinfo5}.SelectMany(Function(arr) arr).ToArray()`. That's all. If you prefer a `List(Of FileSystemInfo)`, then use method 1. Then just pass `FS_file_info_ALL` to the method.

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```
    Dim SINGLE_FSinfo_ALL As New List(Of FileSystemInfo)
    SINGLE_FSinfo_ALL.AddRange(FSinfo1)
    SINGLE_FSinfo_ALL.AddRange(FSinfo2)
    '...  etc.
```

Comment: Thanks alot. Appreciated.